# How to send Date to stored procedure waiting for Date?

Tags: javascript, jquery, stored-procedures

I have stored procedure which is accepting @FromDate and @ToDate, how can i get the value from 2 datepickers and do ajax to it with the parameters so i will get the data needed?

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: DataResource,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            from: $("#date_from").val(),
            to: $("#date_to").val()
        },
        success: function(data, txtstatus, jqxhr) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (jqxhr, errortext, errorthrown) {
            console.log(errorthrown);
        }
    })
```

`#date_from` and `#date_to` are the values from the datepickers. There is server side code to process the stored procedure. I just dont know how to pass the 2 parameters in the `data` property. Any help?

Comment: What's your backend language receiving the ajax data?

Comment: the ajax is fine on the face of it, but how you call the stored procedure depends on many things, but primarily on the backend language and database engine that you're using on the server. You've told us nothing about that. Whatever your language is, unless it's very obscure there will be dozens of examples online of how to accept a HTTP request, and how to call a stored procedure, and how to return a HTTP response using JSON. Plug all those bits together and you've got your code. If you get stuck with it, post the broken code here and people will help. As it is, this question is too vague.